# Merge [leaflet] and [leafletjs]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The tags in question:

- [tag:leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/leaflet/info)
- [tag:leafletjs](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/leafletjs/info)

According to their tag wikis, they appear to point to the same site as their official site. [leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/leaflet) has roughly 1000 questions, while [leafletjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/leafletjs) only has around 25 questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have edited and retagged these questions, and now the [leafletjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/leafletjs) tag has no questions anymore.

Comment: Requiescat in pace, [tag:leafletjs]. Rest in peace. Thanks for helping, ProgramFOX. I guess the next step is to propose a tag synonym for that, so I'll see who I can contact to propose the synonym in my place (since my answer score for that tag is 0)

Comment: @ChrisForrence: No, that's not necessary, the tag will be removed by an automated process.

Comment: Right, but I'd figure that we'd want a synonym of leaflet to be leafletjs. That way, it doesn't pop up again.

Comment: @ChrisForrence: If someone sees now that the tag is no longer in use and that there is a leaflet tag, it's unlikely that someone will re-create the tag.

Comment: Unlikely, certainly, but possible (considering leaflet is two years old and that leafletjs was one month old). You're right though; _if_ it happens.

Comment: @ChrisForrence: I see your point, but the tag will probably be deleted before it becomes a synonym.